# How to foresee the original size of an app before submitting to app store

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am going to create an app for iOS.And it requires a large number of images.So i am really tensed about the final size of my app.I would like to know is there any way to determine the final size  of the app  before  creating the app binary and submitting to the app store 
 .I mean if I right click on the project folder and select getInfo,then the size shown is 20 MB(i didn't create the app binary).Now I would like to know ,after creating the app binary from my Xcode project,what will happen to my 20 MB.

Comment: you can check the size for all apps installed on yoru device. Since you will want to test it on a device you can check here `Settings -> General -> Usage`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Archive the project (Product-->Archive, need to have iOS device selected instead of simulator)
- This will automatically open the organiser
- In the organiser there is an "estimate App Store size" button right under the icon:

[image]

You may find that the app store size differs from the size of your built IPA file - this is because of the encryption and signing used to create apps for the app store.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just build the app without submitting it?